# Why SELECT COUNT(id) is so slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 1M+ records and I have a BTREE index on the column `x`, which also is foreign key:

```
id      | x
---------------
1       | 209
2       | 210
...
1000000 | 209
```

Now I'm running:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t WHERE x = 209
```

It takes 250ms (very slow!) This is what I'm getting via the `EXPLAIN`:

```
Fina­lize­ Aggr­egat­e (cos­t=20­993.­19..­2099­3.19­ rows­=1 widt­h=8)­
  ->­; Gath­er (cos­t=20­993.­09..­2099­3.19­ rows­=1 widt­h=8)­
  Work­ers Plan­ned:­ 1
  ->­; Part­ial Aggr­egat­e (cos­t=19­993.­09..­1999­3.09­ rows­=1 widt­h=8)­
  ->­; Para­llel­ Seq Scan­ on t (cos­t=0.­00..­1982­0.19­ rows­=345­789 widt­h=4)­
  Filt­er: (x = 209)
```

This is the index:

```
CREA­TE INDE­X idx_1 ON publ­ic.t­ USIN­G btre­e (x)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are a lot of rows that match the condition, **and** you count `id`. The latter means that PostgreSQL cannot use an index only scan, because it has to fetch `id` from the table. This is because, like most aggregate functions, `count()` will only count values that are `NOT NULL`, as specified by the SQL standard.

If `id` is not nullable, and the table was recently `VACUUM`ed (so that the *visibility map* has most blocks marked “all visible”), then you would be faster with:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE x = 209;
```

See [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/) for more ruminations about the speed of `count()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is estimated to return 345,­789 rows out of 1,000,000.

Based on this estimate, Postgres will need to read records on all the data pages.  I think Postgres always refers to the data pages, even when using a covering index, because it has to check for various types of locks and dirty data.

Because it needs to read all the pages, Postgres makes the reasonable assumption that it is faster to sequentially scan them rather than going through the index.

Indexes are useful for filtering when they reduce the number of data pages that need to be read.  This query does not appear to be doing that.

EDIT:

There is no real solution to this problem.  You could create a summary table which is maintained by triggers.  That would add load to `insert`/`update`/`delete`, which might be undesirable.